# Автоматически добавить нумерацию в имени

Tags: php, mysql

Вопрос довольно короткий. При регистрации пользователь вводит свой логин, а в MySQL поле `login` является уникальным, поэтому, если пользователь вводит существующий логин, то надо, чтобы в конце логина добавилась соответствующая количеству цифра.

Например, пользователь вводит логин Dmitry - если в базе такой есть, то автоматический добавляется Dmitry1 - а если и это есть, то соответственно Dmitry2 - и т.д.

Как можно это сделать?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: А зачем вам это? Как пользователь потом логиниться будет? Вы заставляете его запоминать, что он "Максим123235"? Вы каким-то не тем путем идете

Comment: Я хочу максимально быструю регистрацию сделать. После регистрации сможет изменить логин, если захочет.

Comment: А что будет, если захочет зарегистрироваться `Dmitriy`, а в базе уже есть `Dmit`?

Comment: `Dmitry` и `Dmit` разные логины

Comment: А что должно произойти, если уже есть 100 пользователей `Dmitry, Dmitry1, Dmitry2, ..., Dmitry11, ... Dmitry99`, а новый пользователь захочет ввести логин `Dmitry1`?

Comment: @Yaant, логины создаются автоматически, берутся из названии почтового ящика :)

Comment: @Максуд так если у вас логин делается автоматом из почтового ящика, тогда причем тут логины с нумерацией в конце? у вас уже логины будут уникальными

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, могут два Дмитрия зарегаться с разной почты: `dmitry@gmail.com` и `dmitry@mail.ru`

Comment: А чем *dmitry@gmail.com* не логин? Или, хотя бы *dmitrygmailcom*? А остальным можно показывать уже просто *dmitry*

Comment: @"Максуд и что? у одного логин будет dmitry@gmail.com, у другого соответственно dmitry@mail.com   В чем тут проблема? А для индивидуальной идентификации испльзуется уже ник... который в настройках задать можно будет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Думаю, верно говорите. Я думал использовать никнеймы для логина, сейчас решил сделать лучше почту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если пользователям будет доступно изменения почтового адреса, то логичнее всего **идентифицировать** пользователя по уникальному номеру.

**аутентификацию** же проводить по текущему почтовому адресу.

а отображаемое имя можно сделать и неуникальным: пусть пользователи называют себя как хотят.

Comment: Спасибо! Такое решение правильное. Буду делать.

Answer (score 0):

Сохранять вводимое пользователем имя в одном поле, а номер - в другом;
сделать оба поля уникальным ключом (есть ограничение длины);
сначала выполнять запрос вставки с номером 0, если не вставит и сгенерирует исключение [1062](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146838/handle-error-for-duplicate-entries-php-mysql), пытаться вставить с номером count(имя).

П.С. Может, еще  есть какие-то  более оптимальные способы с автоинкрементом, а то тут аж 3 запроса получается.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [table] (login)
    SELECT CONCAT('Dmitry', IF(COUNT(*)>0,(COUNT(*)+1),'')) 
    FROM [table] WHERE login='Dmitry'
```

Делаем `SELECT` из этой таблицы, проверяя на наличие `login` `Dmitry`.
Если есть - увеличиваем на 1
Если нет - используем пустое место
И все это вставляем в `INSERT INTO`

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать регулярное выражение. Если есть в логине цифра, то берем её и увеличиваем. Если нет цифры возвращаем логин без изменений
Код примерный на javascript. Но сделать в данном направлении можно.

```js
function newLogin(oldLogin) {
  var expr = /([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)/g;
  if (expr.test(oldLogin)) {
    expr.lastIndex = 0;
    var loginParts = expr.exec(oldLogin);
    var num = parseInt(loginParts[2]);
    num++;
    var newLogin = loginParts[1] + num;
    return newLogin;
  }
  return oldLogin;
}
```

`var loginName = newLogin('sergey123')`;

Я не спец в регулярках, поэтому что-то мог пропустить.